# Multicolumns inside an align* environment

Tags: align, multicol

I have a lot of items in a list inside an align* environment, I tried using the multicol package to make the list compile into a three-column list inside align*, but the align* list keeps going beyond the margins of the document, so the question is: how can I make this happen?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{align*}
        one & \;1 \\
        two & \;2 \\
        three & \;3 \\
        four & \;4 \\
        five & \;5 \\
        six & \;6 \\
        seven & \;7 \\
        eight & \;8 \\
        nine & \;9 \\
        zero & \;0 \\
        one & \;1 \\
        two & \;2 \\
        three & \;3 \\
        four & \;4 \\
        five & \;5 \\
        six & \;6 \\
        seven & \;7 \\
        eight & \;8 \\
        nine & \;9 \\
        zero & \;0 \\
        one & \;1 \\
        two & \;2 \\
        three & \;3 \\
        four & \;4 \\
        five & \;5 \\
        six & \;6 \\
        seven & \;7 \\
        eight & \;8 \\
        nine & \;9 \\
        zero & \;0 \\
        one & \;1 \\
        two & \;2 \\
        three & \;3 \\
        four & \;4 \\
        five & \;5 \\
        six & \;6 \\
        seven & \;7 \\
        eight & \;8 \\
        nine & \;9 \\
        zero & \;0 \\
        one & \;1 \\
        two & \;2 \\
        three & \;3 \\
        four & \;4 \\
        five & \;5 \\
        six & \;6 \\
        seven & \;7 \\
        eight & \;8 \\
        nine & \;9 \\
        zero & \;0 \\
        \end{align*}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the actual contents of `align`? Is it just the numbers?

Comment: The content is actually just words, so I'm using the \text{} command to align a word with it's corresponding plural word in German. So each line in the align* looks like this:

Comment: \text{das Buch} & \text{die Bücher} \\

Comment: If you're aligning text, I don't think using 'align' is the best option here. Align is better suited for math contents.

Comment: Any news? You got two answers ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tabbing`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{tabbing}
  \hspace*{5em}\=\kill
  das Buch \> die Büche \\
  one \> 1 \\
  two \> 2 \\
  three \> 3 \\
  four \> 4 \\
  five \> 5 \\
  six \> 6 \\
  seven \> 7 \\
  eight \> 8 \\
  nine \> 9 \\
  zero \> 0 \\
  one \> 1 \\
  two \> 2 \\
  three \> 3 \\
  four \> 4 \\
  five \> 5 \\
  six \> 6 \\
  seven \> 7 \\
  eight \> 8 \\
  nine \> 9 \\
  zero \> 0 \\
  one \> 1 \\
  two \> 2 \\
  three \> 3 \\
  four \> 4 \\
  five \> 5 \\
  six \> 6 \\
  seven \> 7 \\
  eight \> 8 \\
  nine \> 9 \\
  zero \> 0 \\
  one \> 1 \\
  two \> 2 \\
  three \> 3 \\
  four \> 4 \\
  five \> 5 \\
  six \> 6 \\
  seven \> 7 \\
  eight \> 8 \\
  nine \> 9 \\
  zero \> 0 \\
  one \> 1 \\
  two \> 2 \\
  three \> 3 \\
  four \> 4 \\
  five \> 5 \\
  six \> 6 \\
  seven \> 7 \\
  eight \> 8 \\
  nine \> 9 \\
  zero \> 0
\end{tabbing}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

This reserves 5em for the left column. Adapt it to your need.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may have to manually decide the end of each column at which you would like to break and then end the `align` and use `\columnbreak` then start new `align` for the 2nd column, and so on. For better alignment of the column contents to be always kept at the top, use `\vfill\null` after `\columnbreak` may be helpful.

(I did not think using `\'` would be useful in your case)

You then get something like this

[image]

The full code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{align*}
             & \text{First column} & 0  \\
             & one                 & 1  \\
             & two                 & 2  \\
             & three               & 3  \\
             & four                & 4  \\
             & five                & 5  \\
             & six                 & 6  \\
             & seven               & 7  \\
             & eight               & 8  \\
             & nine                & 9  \\
             & ten                 & 10 \\
             & one                 & 1  \\
             & two                 & 2  \\
             & three               & 3  \\
             & four                & 4  \\
             & five                & 5  \\
             & six                 & 6  \\
             & seven               & 7  \\
             & eight               & 8  \\
             & nine                & 9  \\
             & ten                 & 10 \\
             & one                 & 1  \\
             & two                 & 2  \\
             & three               & 3  \\
             & four                & 4  \\
             & five                & 5  \\
             & six                 & 6  \\
             & seven               & 7  \\
             & eight               & 8  \\
             & nine                & 9  \\
             & ten                 & 10
        \end{align*}
    \vfill\null
    \columnbreak
        \begin{align*}
             & \text{Second column} & 0  \\
             & one                  & 1  \\
             & two                  & 2  \\
             & three                & 3  \\
             & four                 & 4  \\
             & five                 & 5  \\
             & six                  & 6  \\
             & seven                & 7  \\
             & eight                & 8  \\
             & nine                 & 9  \\
             & ten                  & 10 \\
             & one                  & 1  \\
             & two                  & 2  \\
             & three                & 3  \\
             & four                 & 4  \\
             & five                 & 5  \\
             & six                  & 6  \\
             & seven                & 7  \\
             & eight                & 8  \\
             & nine                 & 9  \\
             & ten                  & 10 \\
             & one                  & 1  \\
             & two                  & 2  \\
             & three                & 3  \\
             & four                 & 4  \\
             & five                 & 5  \\
             & six                  & 6  \\
             & seven                & 7  \\
             & eight                & 8  \\
             & nine                 & 9  \\
             & ten                  & 10
        \end{align*}
\vfill\null
\columnbreak
        \begin{align*}
             & \text{Third column} & 0  \\
             & one                 & 1  \\
             & two                 & 2  \\
             & three               & 3  \\
             & four                & 4  \\
             & five                & 5  \\
             & six                 & 6  \\
             & seven               & 7  \\
             & eight               & 8  \\
             & nine                & 9  \\
             & ten                 & 10 \\
             & one                 & 1  \\
             & two                 & 2  \\
             & three               & 3  \\
             & four                & 4  \\
             & five                & 5  \\
             & six                 & 6  \\
             & seven               & 7  \\
             & eight               & 8  \\
             & nine                & 9  \\
             & ten                 & 10 \\
             & one                 & 1  \\
             & two                 & 2  \\
             & three               & 3  \\
             & four                & 4  \\
             & five                & 5  \\
             & six                 & 6  \\
             & seven               & 7  \\
             & eight               & 8  \\
             & nine                & 9  \\
             & ten                 & 10
        \end{align*}
    \vfill\null
    \end{multicols}
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a table, isn't it?

In three column of tables you can write it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{First column}}\\
one         & 1  \\
two         & 2  \\
three       & 3  \\
four        & 4  \\
five        & 5  \\
six         & 6  \\
seven       & 7  \\
eight       & 8  \\
nine        & 9  \\
ten         & 10 \\
one         & 1  \\
two         & 2  \\
three       & 3  \\
four        & 4  \\
five        & 5  \\
six         & 6  \\
seven       & 7  \\
eight       & 8  \\
nine        & 9  \\
ten         & 10 \\
\end{tabular}
    \quad
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Second column}}\\
one         & 1  \\
two         & 2  \\
three       & 3  \\
four        & 4  \\
five        & 5  \\
six         & 6  \\
seven       & 7  \\
eight       & 8  \\
nine        & 9  \\
ten         & 10 \\
one         & 1  \\
two         & 2  \\
three       & 3  \\
four        & 4  \\
five        & 5  \\
six         & 6  \\
seven       & 7  \\
eight       & 8  \\
nine        & 9  \\
ten         & 10 \\
\end{tabular}
    \quad
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Third column}}  \\
one         & 1  \\
two         & 2  \\
three       & 3  \\
four        & 4  \\
five        & 5  \\
six         & 6  \\
seven       & 7  \\
eight       & 8  \\
nine        & 9  \\
ten         & 10 \\
one         & 1  \\
two         & 2  \\
three       & 3  \\
four        & 4  \\
five        & 5  \\
six         & 6  \\
seven       & 7  \\
eight       & 8  \\
nine        & 9  \\
ten         & 10 \\
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]